# Greater than or Less than equal to

Tags: fortran90

How to write `(0>x<1)` i.e, x must lies between 0 and 1 in FORTRAN.
`(0 .GE. x .LE. 1)` or `(x .GE. 0 And x .LE. 1)` is it right?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.and.` if you want to make more than one comparison.

Also, `.GE.` and `.LE.` are going to give you greater than/equal to and less than/equal to. 
You want to use `.gt.` (greater than) and `.lt.` (less than):

```
program cmp
  real :: x(1:4) = (/0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0/)
  do i=1,4
     if (x(i) .gt. 0 .and. x(i) .lt. 1) then
        print *, x(i), "in range"
     else
        print *, x(i), "out of range"
     endif
  enddo
end program cmp
```

output:

```
  0.250000000     in range
  0.500000000     in range
  0.750000000     in range
   1.00000000     out of range
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write this:

```
x .GT. 0 .AND. x .LT. 1
```

Personally, these days I'd use the modern forms of the relational operators, and I always like my less-than/greater-than expressions to have the chevrons opening to the right, so I'd write your expression as

```
0 < x .AND. x < 1
```

Answer (score -3):

x .GT. 0 AND x .LT. 1

I hope I helped you out :)

Comment: This does not offer syntactically correct Fortran, the keyword `and` is incomplete without bracketing stops, *ie* `.and.`.